# ColdFusion ORM is loading base component rather than derived component?

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Let's say we have a `Request` base component and `RequestA`, `RequestB` subclasses mapped using a table per subclass, without a discriminator.

We always did `entityLoadByPk('Request', someSubclassEntityId)` and the method would return an instance of the `RequestA` or `RequestB` component.

Somehow, it just stopped behaving like that this morning and the code haven't changed at all. The `entityLoadByPk` function now return instances of `Request` rather than derived components.

To make sure the code did not changed, we copy-pasted the entire application on another ColdFusion box (running CF11) and it behaved just like it used to do on our CF9 box.

Obviously, there must be a setting or something that have changed on the CF9 box, but we looked at everything we could think off and we simply cannot find any explanation.

The problem still persists even after we rebooted the server and cleared all possible caches we could think of (Template Cache, Component Cache, and we also called ormEvictQueries and ormEvictEntity).

Here's the ORM settings:

```
<cfset this.ormSettings = {
    dialect = 'MicrosoftSQLServer',
    eventHandling = true,
    flushAtRequestEnd = false,
    logSql = true,
    saveMapping = false,
    cfcLocation = domainModelLocation
}>
```

Here's a mapping example (I stripped unnecessary relations):

```
<!--- IPSRequest.cfc --->
<cfcomponent persistent="true" table="IPSRequest" lazy="no">
    <cfproperty name="id" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" column="id" generator="assigned">

</cfcomponent>

<!--- IPSInfoManFileTracerRequest.cfc --->
<cfcomponent 
    persistent="yes" 
    extends="IPSRequest" 
    table="IPSInfoManFileTracerRequest"
    joincolumn="ips_request_id">

    <!--- The id property was repeated because of a bug --->
    <cfproperty name="id" type="numeric" fieldtype="id" column="ips_request_id" generator="assigned">

</cfcomponent>
```

Here's the generated mappings from the CF9 box:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="IPSRequest" lazy="false"
        name="cfc:charities.cts.cfc.model.ips.request.IPSRequest" table="IPSRequest">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column length="10" name="id"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="InfoManFileTracerRequest" lazy="true"
        name="cfc:CHARITIES.CTS.cfc.model.ips.request.InfoManFileTracerRequest" table="IPSInfoManFileTracerRequest">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column length="10" name="ips_request_id"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here's the mappings generated on the CF11 box with the same code:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="IPSRequest" lazy="false"
        name="cfc:charities.cts.cfc.model.ips.request.IPSRequest" table="IPSRequest">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column length="10" name="id"/>
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <joined-subclass entity-name="InfoManFileTracerRequest"
        extends="cfc:charities.cts.cfc.model.ips.request.IPSRequest"
        lazy="true"
        name="cfc:charities.CTS.cfc.model.ips.request.InfoManFileTracerRequest" table="IPSInfoManFileTracerRequest">
        <key column="ips_request_id"/>
    </joined-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

We can see that the mappings seems incorrect on the CF9 box, but it used to work just fine with the same code.

The latest hotfix applied on the CF9 box was `hf902-00007.jar` and was done in 2014.

I must say that I'm puzzled and have no idea what would have changed the behavior?

**EDIT:**

We upgraded our CF9 box to CF11 and the problem went away, despite the fact that we used the migration tool to import configuration settings.

We are happy that it did fix the problem, but are very worried of not knowing what affected the behavior and to see how fragile ColdFusion can be.

Our production box still runs on CF9 for now...